# Undefined when trying to get the upper bound of array?

Tags: javascript

I was just thinking back to the good old days when I used to use VBScript (good old days?!?!? What am I thinking?), and I remember using two very useful methods with arrays, these were UBound and LBound. Now I don't think JavaScript has these and if I wanted to make my own I could extend the object however, I just tried doing this to return the upperbound item (or the last item of the array)

```
var myArray = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','seven', 8, 'nine','10'];
document.write(myArray.length + ' ' + myArray[myArray.length]);
```

the `myArray.length` returns what it should however when I try and output the last item using `myArray[myArray.length]` I get `undefined`? Anyone know why this is?

Thanks

Comment: Javascript array starts with `0`

Comment: And don't forget that there can also be undefined elements in the _middle_ of the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The indexes start at 0. The last element is at `myArray.length - 1`

Answer (score 6):

The last element of `myArray` is at `myArray.length - 1`, since arrays in Javascript are 0-indexed. So , `myArray[myArray.length -1]` is what you're looking for.